# vite directive appears on a blank white page in new laravel/jetstream/inertia project

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vite, inertiajs, laravel-jetstream

im new to jetstream and inertia......so im trying to learn these, however, creating a new project has vite come up as the asset bundler. when i run php artisan serve, a balank white page with the @vite directive appears instaed of the app.blade.php. i have not added any new code, the project is fresh.[image]

what could i do, to fix the display